Hyperplane bundle $\mathcal{O}(d)$ and its sections in terms of coordinates
The following is a passage from a set of lecture notes that I'm reading regarding the hyperplane bundle $\mathcal{O}(d) \to \Bbb CP^n$.

One way of constructing a section of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ is to start with a homogeneous
holomorphic degree-$d$ polynomial $f ∶ \Bbb C^{n+1} \to \Bbb C$ and restrict it to each $1$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb C^{n+1}$. This gives a section $\varphi_f:\Bbb CP^n \to \mathcal{O}(d)$ given explicitly by $$\varphi_f(\xi)=f\vert_{\xi}.$$ To see that this section is holomorphic, choose affine coordinates $(z^1,\dots,z^n) \leftrightarrow [z^1,\dots,1,\dots,z^n]$ on the open set $U_\alpha \subset \Bbb CP^n$. Over $U_\alpha$, we have a local holomorphic frame $s_\alpha: U_\alpha \to \mathcal{O}(-1)$ defined by $$s_\alpha([w^0,\dots,w^n)]=\left([w],\frac{1}{w^\alpha}(w^0,\dots,w^n)\right).$$ The section $\varphi_f$ applied to $s_\alpha$ gives $$\varphi_f(s_\alpha([z^1,\dots,1,\dots,z^n]) ) = f(z^1,\dots,1,\dots,z^n).$$

I'm getting slightly confused here with the different coordinates systems. Shouldn't
$$
\varphi_f(s_\alpha([z^1,\dots,1,\dots,z^n]) ) 
$$ be the restriction of $f$ on to the line $[z^1,\dots,1,\dots,z^n]$ instead of evaluation of $f$ on the vector $(z^1,\dots,1,\dots,z^n) \in \Bbb C^{n+1}$?
